# Arabic for Mathjax

Tags: arabic, mathjax

I have installed Mathjax.2.7.5 and arabic-Mathjax from https://github.com/OmarIthawi/arabic-mathjax
I use them locally without server, without Internet-connection
i have modified the example "sample-signals.html" to get some arabic equation:
[Arabic-Mathjax1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r5RE.png)

my code is:

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--
 | This example shows how to use MathJax's signal mechanism to find out 
 | about what MathJax is doing, and to hook into various events as they 
 | occur.
-->
<link href='Amiri' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:/4-11-2019/MathJax-2.7.5/arabic/dist/arabic.css">
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
//  Configure MathJax
  //
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "D:/4-11-2019/MathJax-2.7.5/arabic/dist/unpacked/arabic.js"],
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js", "autoload-all.js"]
  },
  'HTML-CSS': {
        undefinedFamily: 'Amiri'
    },
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [
      ['$', '$'],
      ["\\(", "\\)"]
    ],
    processEscapes: true
  },
  });
  MathJax.Hub.Register.LoadHook("[MathJax]/extensions/TeX/noUndefined.js",
    function () {MathJax.Hub.Startup.signal.Post("*** noUndefined Loaded ***")});
  MathJax.Hub.Register.LoadHook("[MathJax]/extensions/TeX/AMSmath.js",
    function () {MathJax.Hub.Startup.signal.Post("*** AMSmath Loaded ***")});
  MathJax.Hub.Startup.signal.Post("*** In Startup Configuration code ***");
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("onLoad",function () {
    Message("*** The onLoad handler has run, page is ready to process ***");
  });
  </script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../MathJax.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="D:/4-11-2019/MathJax-2.7.5/MathJax.js"></script>
<style>
  .output {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding: 3px 1em;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
$$\alwaysar{x=1}$$
</p>
<p>
When \(a \ne 0\), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</p>
<p>\[E = mc^2\]</p>
<p>$$\ar{x=1}$$</p>
<p>$\ar{x=1}$</p>
<p>
Messages about mathematics:
<pre id="MathMessages" class="output">
</pre>
</p>

<p>
All Messages:
<pre id="AllMessages" class="output">
</pre>
</p>

<script>
(function () {
var math = document.getElementById("MathMessages");
  var all = document.getElementById("AllMessages");
   window.Message = function (message) {
    MathJax.HTML.addText(all,message);
    MathJax.HTML.addElement(all,"br");
  };
  MathJax.Hub.Register.MessageHook("New Math",function (message) {
    var script = MathJax.Hub.getJaxFor(message[1]).SourceElement();
    MathJax.HTML.addText(math,message.join(" ")+": '"+script.text+"'");
    MathJax.HTML.addElement(math,"br");
  });
  MathJax.Hub.Startup.signal.Interest(function (message) {Message("Startup: "+message)});
  MathJax.Hub.signal.Interest(function (message) {Message("Hub: "+message)});
  Message("##### events above this have already occurred #####");

})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me????

Comment: Hi AAA and welcome to StackOverflow, im failing to see what your issue is here?
What errors do you encounter? (Open Console in your Browser (F12), and look for errors in Console and Network tab )

Comment: the problem is with square root is always appear from left to right but not from right to left!! i have used  <p dir= "rtl" Language = "arabic">, but the problem is always there!!

Comment: Please fix the code snippet to use load MathJax from a CDN rather than locally.